# Динамический массив структур

Tags: c, указатели, структуры

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /*
        Фамилия студента
        Номер зачетки
        Массив из 4 оценок
        ­   Сортировка структур по фамилии или среднему баллу
        ­   Удаление всех зачеток троечников
    */

    const int n=2;
    struct ZACHETKA
    {   
        char last_name[30];
        int no;
        int ocenka[3];
    };
    int j,i;
    ZACHETKA* box = new ZACHETKA[n];
    ZACHETKA tmp;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin.sync();
        cout<<"Vvedite Familiy"<<endl;
        cin.getline(box[i].last_name, 30);
        cout<<"Vvedite nomer"<<endl;
        cin>>box[i].no;
        cout<<"Vvedite ocenki (4)"<<endl;
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            cin>>box[i].ocenka[j];
    }

    //- Cортировка по фамилии
    for(i=n-1; i>0 ; i--)
        for(j=0; j<i ; j++)
            if(strcmp( box[ j ].last_name, box[ j+1 ].last_name ) > 0)
            {   
                tmp = box[ j ];
                box[ j ]= box[ j+1 ];
                box[ j+1 ]= tmp;
            }

    //- Удаление всех зачеток троечников
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            if(box[i].ocenka[j] == 3)
                delete [] box[i];

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<box[i].last_name<<endl;
        cout<<box[i].no<<endl;
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            cout<<box[i].ocenka[j]<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Как правильно работать с динамическим массивом структур и почему ошибку выдает на удалении троечников. И почему-то третья оценка в первой введенной зачетке на выводе какое-то левое здоровое число. Ну и хотелось бы услышать какие сразу косяки бросаются в глаза.

Comment: @RubyNub, из ответов и комментариев Вы видимо уже поняли, что основная ошибка - это невозможность использования `delete` для удаления элемента массива.

Вместо этого надо просто "затирать" записи троечников, смещая остальные влево. Допустим найдено `k` троечников. В результате у Вас в массиве должны быть актуальные `n-k` элементов, т.е. потом надо
распечатывать не `n`, а `n-k` строк. 

(Размер же выделенной под массив памяти не изменится).

--

Кстати, поиск троечников и перенос актуальных записей влево, можно совместить в одном цикле.

Возможно именно этого хочет от вас препод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код написан плохо, нужно точно определиться, на чем Вы пишете - С, С+ или С++ (С+ - это такая шутка. когда код написан на с++, но максимально в си стиле).

> > почему ошибку выдает на удалении троечников

Посмотрите на Ваш код

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            if(box[i].ocenka[j] == 3)
                delete [] box[i];
```

Если самая первая оценка - тройка, то при проверке второй оценки будет бардак. Потому что  элемент уже удален. А это неправильно. Но проблема в том, что с обычного массива так удалить нельзя. Это не вектор. Но если нужно вывести всех не троешников, то не обязательно удалять. Можно просто пропустить при выводе. В Вашем случае это будет проще.

> > Ну и хотелось бы услышать какие сразу косяки бросаются в глаза.

Самое страшное, что бросается - это следующие строки

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

Первая точно не нужна, а вторая - это для древних компиляторов.

Я немного поправил код, он теперь компилируется чистым С компилятором.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int n=2;
struct ZACHETKA
{   
    char last_name[30];
    int no;
    int ocenka[3];
};

int main()
{
    /*
        Фамилия студента
        Номер зачетки
        Массив из 4 оценок
        ­   Сортировка структур по фамилии или среднему баллу
        ­   Удаление всех зачеток троечников
    */

    int j,i;
    struct ZACHETKA* box = (struct ZACHETKA*)malloc(sizeof(struct ZACHETKA) * n);
    struct ZACHETKA tmp;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        puts("Vvedite Familiy\n");
        scanf("%s", box[i].last_name);

        puts("Vvedite nomer\n");
        scanf("%d", &box[i].no);
        puts("Vvedite ocenki (3)\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &box[i].ocenka[0], &box[i].ocenka[1], &box[i].ocenka[2]);
    }

    //- Cортировка по фамилии
    for(i=n-1; i>0 ; i--)
        for(j=0; j<i ; j++)
            if(strcmp( box[ j ].last_name, box[ j+1 ].last_name ) > 0)
            {   
                tmp = box[ j ];
                box[ j ]= box[ j+1 ];
                box[ j+1 ]= tmp;
            }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           if (box[i].ocenka[j] == 3)
             goto fin; // да, в данном случае это оправдано, это си
        }
        printf("%s\n", box[i].last_name);
        printf("%d\n", box[i].no);
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
            printf("%d ", box[i].ocenka[j]);
         printf("\n");
        fin:;
    }

    free(box);
    return 0;
}
```

Решил причесать немного код и перевести на более приплюснутый си. Я бы сказал, это с с полтора плюсами.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

const int max_number_of_students=2;
const int grades_count = 3;
struct RecordBook // да, так будет зачетка
{   
    std::string last_name;
    int no;
    int grades[grades_count]; // раньше это называлось "ocenka"
};

int main()
{
    /*
        Фамилия студента
        Номер зачетки
        Массив из 4 оценок
        ­   Сортировка структур по фамилии или среднему баллу
        ­   Удаление всех зачеток троечников
    */

    std::vector<RecordBook> box;
    RecordBook t;

    for(int i = 0; i < max_number_of_students; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter Last Name:" << std::endl;
        getline(std::cin, t.last_name);

        std::cout << "Enter Nomer:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> t.no;
        std::cout << "Enter grades (count:"<< grades_count <<")" << std::endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < grades_count; j++)
            std::cin >> t.grades[j];
        // почему эта строка ниже - http://modwind.ru/publ/cpp_io_input_output_advice/6-1-0-7
        std::cin.ignore(50, '\n'); 
        box.push_back(t);
    }

    //- Cортировка по фамилии
    // Здесь хорошо бы применить стандартный алгоритм сортировки, но боюсь это будет перебор.
    for(size_t i=box.size()-1; i>0 ; i--)
        for(size_t j=0; j<i ; j++)
            if(box[ j ].last_name > box[ j+1 ].last_name)
            {   
               std::swap(box[j], box[j+1]);
               // три строки ниже - олд-скул вариант.
               //RecordBook t = box[j];
               //box[j] = box[j+1];
               //box[j+1] = t;
            }

    for(size_t i=0; i<box.size(); i++)
    {
        bool is_find = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < grades_count; j++) {
           if (box[i].grades[j] == 3) {
             is_find = true;
             break;
           }
        }
        if (is_find)
           continue;
        std::cout << box[i].last_name << std::endl << box[i].no << std::endl;

        for(int j=0; j<grades_count; j++)
            std::cout << box[i].grades[j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Код немножко причесанный, транслит переделан на более-менее английский, много магических номеров вынесено в константы. Кол-во студентов, которых нужно ввести, теперь задается только в одном месте и это легко поменять. Много изменений, которые бы я сделал, я  не включил (мне потом ещё на 20 страниц расшифровки писать для преподавателя).

Comment: Ого сколько всякой "каки". А можете показать на плюсах? Потому что все-таки лучше сразу на плюсах буду, чем с таким примитивом извращаться.

Comment: Цикл с `j < 4` не вполне верен, надо до 3 — и наверное лучше объявить именованную константу.

Comment: @RubyNub - Вы уже определитесь. чистый си - плохо, с++ - плохо. @VladD от минус поставил кто-то просто так.

Comment: @KoVadim, пришел к выводу, что буду стараться делать упор на плюсы и по мере повышения уровня знаний писать без всяких подобий С+. Помогите пожалуйста с реализаций данной проблемы на чистом С++, а я возьму хотя бы того же страуструпа и буду потихонечку разбираться.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, все действительно проще, если использовать стандартные контейнеры. Но я все-таки не пониманию, почему нельзя просто удалить зачетки с тройками? И хотелось бы узнать, что за стандартный алгоритм сортировки вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: - [Стандартный алгоритм сортировки std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Comment: @RubyNub, конечно удалить можно. См [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/). Там же [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

Пример удаления чисел кратных трем из `vector <int>v;`

      for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        if (v[i] % 3 == 0)
          v.erase(v.begin()+i);

Однако, если хотите мое личное мнение, то сначала лучше все это пройти на Си, чтобы по возможности прочувствовать, так сказать, изнутри.

Потом ошибок (конечно я не имею в виду синтаксис и т.п. тривиальщину) меньше будет. 

--

Тяжело в учении - легко в бою.

Answer (score 1):

(Эта часть ответа — для C++).

Для начала, используйте стандартные контейнеры и `std::string`. Сразу бросается в глаза, честно.

Затем, разбейте код на процедуры! Маленькие, с **осмысленными** названиями.

Затем, инкапсулируйте операции типа сравнения внутрь ваших классов. Сейчас вы пишете как будто на чистом C, только без процедур.

Затем, не изобретайте велосипеды там, где не нужно. Например, ручная сортировка вставками никому не интересна. Используйте библиотечную сортировку — уменьшайте количество ошибок.

---

Теперь в рамках чистого C.

Во-первыx, вы не должны копировать потенциально большие структуры по значению (`tmp = box[ j ]` и т. п.). Храните в массиве указатели на структуры.

Затем, в "Удаление всех зачеток троечников" у вас почему-то цикл по `j` до 4. Это неверно, у вас ведь всего 3 оценки. Вообще, этой ошибки бы не случилось, если б вы воспользовались вместо литерала 4 именованной константой.

Затем, `delete [] box[i]` — нельзя. Вы не можете удалить элемент из середины нативного массива, сорри, это вам не C++. Вы должны делать по-другому: сдвинуть все элементы влево на один, и запомнить новую длину. Сложно? Да. Ещё в следующей итерации цикла вам надо не ошибиться с индексом.

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста что есть стандартные контейнеры и почему же лучше засорять код постоянными std::string?

Comment: Стандартные контейнеры — это `std::vector`, `std::map`, `std::set` и тому подобные. Вы должны использовать их вместо нативных массивов.

Вы и правда _не знаете_, чем отличается нативная строка от `std::string`? Пока вы сами себе не ответите на этот вопрос, для вас применение правильных строк будет считаться "засорением".

Вот потому, что вы не работаете с лёгкими в использовании классами C++, а пытаетесь писать очень низкоуровневый код (без должного на то умения), и возникают ошибки вроде "левое здоровое число".

Comment: Не давайте вредных советов. 

Это учебное задание и суть его в том чтобы как раз писать велосипеды, тем самым приобретая неободимые знания.

Comment: Извиняюсь за тег с++ писанина естественно на с, а на счет процедур, к сожалению пока мне нельзя прибегать к их использованию. Про std::string только что понял.

Comment: @1101_debian: **нет**. Писать на языке C++ так нельзя. Код написан на C без процедур. Я бы ещё понял, если бы ТС написал свой класс строки и свой контейнер, но пользоваться нативными массивами и строками в C++ без крайней на то необходимости — абсолютное зло.

Comment: @1101_debian, спасибо
@VladD а за С++ извиняюсь вторично) Писал уже выше

Comment: @RubyNub: **нельзя** пользоваться процедурами? Гхм. Скажите вашему преподавателю — это _не пользоваться_ процедурами нельзя, пусть вылезает из каменного века. (Ну хорошо, не скажите, вам ещё у него зачёт получать, но хоть подумайте так.)

Comment: Если это не C++, а C, то (1) поменяйте теги к вопросу, и (2) уберите `cin` и `cout`, `new` и `delete`.

Comment: @VladD, не мелите чушь, пожалуйста. К тожу ТС сказал что С++ здесь нет.

Человек должен обучаться и понимать азы. 

Следуя вашей логике ТС лучше заюзать реляционную БД, а не писать что-то свое.

Comment: @VladD, ну тег поправил, а вот без cin cout delete и new не могу. Хоть и смесь какая-то получается но это же для инста и там такому учат. Насчет процедур, если вы о пользовательских функциях, то да вы правы естественно, но с ними вот скоро познакомят, а пока приходится вот такой уг творить. Может к коду все-таки вернемся, как бы исправить это

Comment: @RubyNub: Ну, написал. А что за вуз, позвольте полюбопытствовать?

Comment: @RubyNun, на Вашем месте я бы написал так как нужно. Можно конечно делать такое чудо, как рекомендует преподаватель, то может быть Вы неверно выбрали институт?

Comment: > может быть Вы неверно выбрали институт

Вероятно, вас это удивит, но в "лучшем техническом вузе" этой страны встречаются похожие ситуации. Более того, весь первый курс состоит из них на 95%.

Comment: я не знаю, что такое "лучший технический вуз" этой страны. Когда я учился (я так понимаю, я учился не в "этой стране"), то за подобный код можно было получить плохую оценку сразу. Мой институт точно входит в десятку лучших технических, но специальность не программирование, даже близко не программирование.


Хотя, если честно, с одной стороны я поддерживаю таких преподавателей - они убивают конкурентов ещё на подлете:), но с другой стороны мне стает очень грустно...

Comment: @KoVadim, ну Вы и строги!

По сути-то, код как код. 

Есть только глубокое непонимание автором сути операторов `new` и `delete`, вследствии  чего возникает некая *мистическая* связь между переменной `n` (которая видимо должна по его задумке уменьшаться при `delete`) и указателем на `struct ZACHETKA`, которому присваивается `new ZACHETKA [n]`.

Т.е. автор сильно переоценивает "интеллектуальность" компилятора C++.

Почему-то мне кажется, что при использовании malloc/free (scanf/printf) подобные идеи возникают реже.