# Динамический массив структур (на си)

Tags: структуры, динамические-массивы, динамические-структуры

Нужен пример кода с динамическим массивом структур, который будет автоматически расширяться, если пользователь захочет добавить еще одну запись. Язык: си

Comment: Возможно, [связан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/204140/317064)

Comment: [man realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)